# cache isn't being cleared after clean refresh

Tags: css

I'm surprised with my website that when I press ctrl+f5 then it uses the stylesheet that I would expect and again after ctrl+f5, however if I press just f5 it uses the styles I would not expect.

And for clarification I know to clear the cache by querying the link of stylesheet like `.css?v=1.0` but I wanted to know why it is switching back again to cached stylesheet file after clean refresh?

I faced this problem twice on different websites so I've asked here. I hope someone might have solved this type of problem before.

Comment: what about just using private browsing? no cache.

Comment: even in incognito view of chrome it's not taking new styles but private browsing in firefox it's working fine.